# Rails prettyPhoto does not show photo with jquery (instead redirect to photo page)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, prettyphoto

i do all instruction for use prettyPhoto in https://github.com/hiq5/prettyphoto-rails.

and i do this to show a single photo( not gallery )

```
=link_to image_tag(photo.photo_url(:thumb).to_s, :alt => photo.name ,:class => "img-polaroid"), photo.photo_url, :rel => 'prettyPhoto'
```

but still redirect to photo url and show photo, and doesn't use jQuery to show it on the current page.

i check it with chrome development tools, there isn't any error.

i use haml to generate views (instead erb), and carrierwave to upload photos.
by the way I use twitter bootstrap.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? 'doesn't work' is somewhat unspecific...

Comment: in where did you call `$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto(...)`?

Comment: @peter i don't use this line you write anywhere! I think prettyPhoto gem in Rails do this for me. if it's not, where i should add it.

Comment: thank you @PeterWong you give me nice note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the documentation don't tell we should add the following code in bottom of body (html tag)

so we should add the following code

in haml

```
%script{:charset => "utf-8", :type => "text/javascript"}
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
  });
```

in erb or html

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
    });
</script>
```